# Factoring a polynomial over a number field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Consider a polynomial x^3-x-1 and let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be three zeros of the polynomial where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $\beta \not \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and the degree of the splitting field of the polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $6$, the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ should be of degree $2$.
To find the polynomial (by the way, I know it should be $x^2+\alpha x+ \frac{1}{\alpha}$.) I have coded the following

```
sol = x /. Solve[x^3 == x + 1, x];
al = sol[[1]];
be = sol[[2]];
ga = sol[[3]];
MinimalPolynomial[be, x, Extension -> al]
```

However, Mathematica returns an unexpected message;

[image: Unexpected result]

What is wrong with the code? What would be a right way to get correct answer?

Comment: Look at the roots of: x2+αx+1α.  β is not among them.

Comment: @DanielHuber If you try "FullSimplify[be^2 + al be + 1/al]", you would get zero.

Comment: You are right. I only tried Simplify, but it needs FullSimplify.

Comment: `Factor[x^3 - x - 1, Extension -> {sol[[3]]}]` produces

Comment: `-(1/432) (2^(2/3) 3^(5/6) (9 - Sqrt[69])^(1/3) - 
   I 2^(2/3) (3 (9 - Sqrt[69]))^(1/3) - 
   2^(2/3) 3^(5/6) (9 + Sqrt[69])^(1/3) - 
   I 2^(2/3) (3 (9 + Sqrt[69]))^(1/3) - 12 I x) (12 I + 
   3 2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) (9 - Sqrt[69])^(2/3) + 
   I 2^(1/3) (3 (9 - Sqrt[69]))^(2/3) - 
   3 2^(1/3) 3^(1/6) (9 + Sqrt[69])^(2/3) + 
   I 2^(1/3) (3 (9 + Sqrt[69]))^(
    2/3) + (-3 2^(2/3) 3^(5/6) (9 - Sqrt[69])^(1/3) + 
      3 I 2^(2/3) (3 (9 - Sqrt[69]))^(1/3) + 
      3 2^(2/3) 3^(5/6) (9 + Sqrt[69])^(1/3) + 
      3 I 2^(2/3) (3 (9 + Sqrt[69]))^(1/3)) x - 36 I x^2)`.

Comment: I think it might be worth sending in a bug report. `MinimalPolynomial[s, x, Extension -> a]` is calling `ToNumberField[s, a]`, and thus is demanding that `s` already be in the field $\mathbb{Q}[a]$ (as opposed to simply being a root of some polynomial over that field). This means that, for example, it fails even for `MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[2], x, Extension -> I]` (or, even more simply, `Extension -> 1`). It works fine when no extension is given. This...is not how it's supposed to work, right?

Comment: update: it says in the docs that "`MinimalPolynomial[s,x,Extension->a]` finds the characteristic polynomial of $s \in \mathbb{Q}[a]$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}[a]$." i...guess it's intended functionality, and not a bug, then, but i don't know why. maybe some feasibility constraints...?

Comment: In the vein of user64494's comment, `FactorList[MinimalPolynomial[be][x], Extension -> al]` seems to contain your polynomial (with $1/\alpha$ represented as $\alpha^2-1$). I wonder if there's a good way to identify it as what you want.

Comment: @thorimur Thanks for your careful comment. By the help of the paragraphs I got a better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MinimalPolynomial[s, x, Extension->a]` finds the characteristic polynomial of the element $s \in \mathbb{Q}[a]$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}[a]$.

https://planetmath.org/characteristicpolynomialofalgebraicnumber

As has been already suggested, you can get the minimal polynomial over a field extension using Factor(List).

```
In[7]:= minpoly[a_, e_, x_] :=                                                  
   Select[First/@FactorList[MinimalPolynomial[a, x], Extension->e],             
      PossibleZeroQ[#/.x->a, Method->"ExactAlgebraics"]&][[1]]                  

In[8]:= minpoly[be, al, x]                                                      

              2                      3                           3       2
Out[8]= -1 + x  + x Root[-1 - #1 + #1  & , 1] + Root[-1 - #1 + #1  & , 1]
```

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable solution!